# coding variable values into classes using R

Tags: r, variables, break, subclass

I have a set of data in which I need to code values of certain variables (numeric) into 3 classes.

My data set is similar to this but has 60 more variables:

```
anim <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
wt <- c(181,179,180.5,201,201.5,245,246.4,189.3,301,354,369,205,199,394,231.3)
data <- data.frame(anim,wt)

> data
   anim    wt
1     1 181.0
2     2 179.0
3     3 180.5
4     4 201.0
5     5 201.5
6     6 245.0
7     7 246.4
8     8 189.3
9     9 301.0
10   10 354.0
11   11 369.0
12   12 205.0
13   13 199.0
14   14 394.0
15   15 231.3
```

I need to code values of the variable "wt" up into 3 classes: (wt >= 179 & wt < 200) = 1; (wt >= 200 & wt < 300) = 2; (wt > 300) = 3

which should give me this

```
> data2
   anim    wt SWT
1     1 181.0   1
2     2 179.0   1
3     3 180.5   1
4     4 201.0   2
5     5 201.5   2
6     6 245.0   2
7     7 246.4   2
8     8 189.3   1
9     9 301.0   3
10   10 354.0   3
11   11 369.0   3
12   12 205.0   2
13   13 199.0   1
14   14 394.0   3
15   15 231.3   2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `cut` method as outlined by @Greg is probably what you want here. One thing to note is that `cut` returns a factor by default, which you can suppress by supplying `labels = FALSE` to return the integer values:

```
cut(data$wt, c(178, 200, 300, Inf), labels = FALSE)
```

Alternatively, if your cutting does not lend itself to natural breaks, you can use `ifelse()`. You can "nest" the ifelse statements similar to Excel. I use "with" to cut down on the typing needed:

```
data$group2 <- with(data, ifelse(wt >= 179 & wt < 200, 1, 
  ifelse(wt >= 200 & wt < 300, 2, 3))
)
```

Comment: good point on the labels. I usually just cast it to a numeric with `as.numeric` to get integer group values.

Comment: @Greg - I imagine it's six in one, 1/2 dozen in the other. I actually didn't realize `cut` would return the numeric values until looking at the help file for the question. I've always used the `as.numeric()` method as well...

Comment: @Chase: While I admit that what Greg provided works, I will also say that what you suggested allows more control and may be flexibility as well.

Comment: @baz - I find ifelse more useful when I am computing a new variables based off of 2 or more existing variables...i.e if "Monday and rainy" then "don't get out of bed"

Comment: @baz, @Chase - nested ifelse statements are great for 3 groups. but if you have 20 groups, it can get unwieldy.

Comment: @Chase,@Greg: i always like to use ifelse but am not really confident when using 2 or more variables to get a new one. Now, i believe that i have that confidence. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @baz : for performance, you better don't nest too many ifelses. `Cut` is designed to do this for you, so use it.

Comment: @Chase: Still on the same example: Instead of putting a range for each level, I just need to divide into 3 equal sized groups.

Answer (score 5):

You can try `cut`

```
anim <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) 
wt <-c(181,179,180.5,201,201.5,245,246.4,
189.3,301,354,369,205,199,394,231.3) 
data <- data.frame(anim,wt)
```

EDIT: fixed group - right = FALSE, got rid of split example.

```
group = cut(data$wt, c(178, 200, 300, Inf), right=FALSE)


data$swt = as.numeric(group)
data
   anim    wt swt
1     1 181.0   1
2     2 179.0   1
3     3 180.5   1
4     4 201.0   2
5     5 201.5   2
6     6 245.0   2
7     7 246.4   2
8     8 189.3   1
9     9 301.0   3
10   10 354.0   3
11   11 369.0   3
12   12 205.0   2
13   13 199.0   1
14   14 394.0   3
15   15 231.3   2
>
```

Comment: I believe that I should have used the term "coding" instead of "breaking", which means that I need to code wt=179<200 as 1; wt=200<300 as 2 and wt>300 as 3. sorry for my mistake!

Comment: @baz - I added code to add the group. You can look at the `right` parameter to include either the left or right side of the interval. I think my left/right parameter is off from your example.

Comment: @baz - I think my data frame matches yours now.

Comment: I imagine `labels = FALSE` is preferred over `as.numeric()` for those that get worked up over such things.

Comment: what if i need to split up my wt variable into 3 equal sized groups or any continuous variable for that matter

Answer (score 2):

I think Greg's answers cover "standard operating procedure", but I find many uses for the findInterval function as well. It naturally returns a number that identifies the interval in the second argument.

```
 data$int <- findInterval(data$wt, c(179, 200, 300, Inf))
 data
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to show an alternate (similar to recode in SPSS) method from package [car](http://cran.r-project.org/package=car):

```
> data$SWT <- with(data, recode(wt, "lo:200=1; 300:hi=3; else=2"))
> data
   anim    wt SWT
1     1 181.0   1
2     2 179.0   1
3     3 180.5   1
4     4 201.0   2
5     5 201.5   2
6     6 245.0   2
7     7 246.4   2
8     8 189.3   1
9     9 301.0   3
10   10 354.0   3
11   11 369.0   3
12   12 205.0   2
13   13 199.0   1
14   14 394.0   3
15   15 231.3   2
```

Comment: I also use the package car in some of my recoding work on categorical variables like: df$newvar <- recode(df$oldvar,"c(1)=2;c(0)=1") but has never used it on continuous varibales. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness and info, the classInt package (on CRAN) is another handy way to classify numbers into classes.